# Is Tinkerpop3 production ready?

Tags: graph, titan, tinkerpop, tinkerpop3

I am currently using Tinkerpop 2.5 in my application to represent a graph in-memory and gremlin to query it. This application will go into production at end of July 2015. I am confused if I should use 2.5 or 3. Currently [Tinkerpop](http://www.tinkerpop.com/) 3.0.0 is in M7 release. I don't see any information on the GA release schedule.

Comment: What is the status of Tinkerpop3 now in 2016?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this time, TinkerPop 2.x is basically in maintenance-mode only (i.e. we've generally frozen development short of major bug fixes).  All effort is focused on TP3 and getting it to GA.  GA has been somewhat delayed as TinkerPop moves to its new home as an Apache project: http://tinkerpop.incubator.apache.org/

Unfortunately, we can't provide much certainty for when GA will be available, so this leaves people starting a project and trying to make the choice between TP2 and TP3 a bit difficult.  I can say that if you use TP2, it has good stability and a very wide number of vendors who support it.  If you use TP3, expect some turmoil in the API on the way to GA and keep in mind that, at this time, you don't have a lot of vendor support for the interfaces though many vendors are committed to having TP3 implementations when GA is in place: http://www.tinkerpop.com/docs/3.0.0-SNAPSHOT/#_graph_vendors

UPDATE: TinkerPop 3.x was released into GA in July 2015 and can now be considered production-ready.  There have been multiple releases since that initial one.  Latest developments can be found on the project home page: http://tinkerpop.apache.org/

Comment: Thank you for clarifying. Will stick with TP2